# P value fromJaccard's index

Tags: r

My table having 40 raw and 4 columns, in that 4 columns first column belongs to one group and the remaining constitute the other group.
using following commands for calculating jaccard's index

```
x <- read.csv(file name,header=T, sep= )
jac <- vegdist(x,method="jaccard")
```

1. from this out file(jac) how can i find the p value for two groups?
2. and how can i plot notched box plot of these two groups?

when i use `boxes(as.matrix(jac)~x$first column,notch=TRUE)`
its showing 40 box plots. why it so?